# Using PHPSecLib, What are some reasons that I get a null version when calling getSupportedVersions()?

Tags: centos, openssh, phpseclib

I am attempting to authenticate with a CentOS server using the PHPSecLib library, and now my password authentication is failing.

The platform that I am running on got a "security upgrade" but I was not involved in that process and what they did to make changes. This has now resulted in `array (   'version' => NULL, )`. The previous platform version would return `array (   'version' => 3, )`

I would guess that this is a bad server configuration, but I am not sure what setting would cause this mis match. There is nothing in the /etc/ssh/sshd_config that is uncommented that would change the protocol

Comment: You need to be logged into an SFTP server to determine the versions that that server supports. If you're unable to log into that server anymore that'd explain that. Maybe you were using password auth and now you need to be using public key auth?

Comment: I can still log in via command line using user/password. And ```ssh -v localhost``` on both boxes looks very similar with no version differences that jump out

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the password was flagged as an expired password. Even though the login was successful, PHPSecLib would fail to login and not give a clear answer as to why.